# How is it proved that 99.7% of all samples are in 6 SDs in Normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

[image]

The property of 68.2%, 95.4%, and 99.7% are amazing. But how do we prove that it always works?

Comment: You approximate the integral $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-3}^3e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: It "always works" because these numbers are... constants !

Answer (score 0):

It is not right to say that such percentage of the sample will *always* be *exactly* such multiple of the standard deviation. (In reality, it will never be.)

In fact, the number of samples that fall in the prescribed range is a random variable that follows a Binomial law (the probability $p$ that a single sample falls in the range is given by the Normal law, and we have a Bernouilli scheme, i.e. repeating $n$ times a yes/no drawing).

For instance, for a normal sample of size $100$, the distribution of the number of samples that fall within two sigmas of the mean is given by the histogram below:

[image]

As you see, the *most probable* value is $96\%$, in about every fifth case (though the *average* value is indeed $95.4\%$.)